# storing 3-4mb of data in frontend/angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, indexeddb

I need to store about 3-4mb of data (USPS address data mapping zip code to county across the entire US) in the frontend code for fast retrieval. The primary use case is that my users will type in their zip code and I need to tell them what counties they are in.

Storing the data in a plain JSON file in the frontend repo seems like a bad idea because it blows up my app size.

I don't want to retrieve it via an API because the input field performs logic that requires the address data on 500-1000ms delayed keystroke.

My main approach now is to load all the data via API when the app is loaded, and store it into IndexedDB if it doesn't exist already. The annoying part here is it's not obviously "instant" to call an API that returns 3mb of data. An optimization here is that I could just return the data for the county or state that I think the user might be in based on `getCurrentPosition()` first (unless not allowed), with a follow up async call to return the rest.

Are there any other strategies that I might be missing?

Comment: Will your individual users really be typing in multiple different things so often that caching it on the client would be helpful? A halfway decent modern server in the same continent should be able to reply with the needed info within 200ms (sometimes a lot less), which should be good enough for most purposes. If you really have to put it on the client, then loading everything into IndexedDB on pageload is exactly what I'd do. You could also make a separate one-time request to your server if the full data is still loading.

Comment: Put it behind an api and make the api suggest based on what the user types. Lets say you start typing a couple of digets you can just suggest the rest and when the user has a full zip then return the full object for the address. Dont give them the full object, cause then you will have the full 3-4mb bottleneck.